# Installed dual boot Win10 and Ubuntu 19.10 - grub problem

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2

Installed dual boot Win10 and Ubuntu 19.10, had problems with it, reinstalled by not deleting anything for 3 times, nothing solved, still login loop and other errors. After watching YT video for deleting Linux partition something went wrong, system rebooted and grub rescue. I tried at least 6 different ways with all solutions I could find. Nothing worked.

Tried Win10 USB bootable to fix, bootrec.exe /fixboot, access denied. After some solutions, /fixboot and /fixmbr - CMD says everything succesful. Still grub rescue.

After that the only thing I knew how, was to format Win10 partition and reinstalled new Win10, had recovery image so no data loss.

Worked perfectly, tried again, this time Ubuntu 18.04. Just before finishing installation, I get that it can't install bootloader and I chose Cancel the installation. It went into Ubuntu, I do all updates, upgrades, try Grub Customizer after one article. Now this one says Failed to get canonical path of /cow. I try to install grub on /dev/sda, error. I reboot and it goes straight to Win10.

Somehow, grub is still somewhere, but corrupt, and I don't know where. As I'm fairly new, I don't quite get anything anymore. I understand I did a mistake doing that YT tutorial somehow, but now I'm just going into circles. I want to be able to boot to both.

I must add this: I'm giving Ubuntu partition on a separate SSD (sdb), Win10 has its own (sda).

Is there a solution for me to repair grub and how? Thank you dearly...

Comment: Sounds like you have Windows in one boot mode, UEFI? and then Ubuntu  in other boot mode BIOS? Both systems must be in same boot mode, preferably UEFI. And both install based on how you boot install media, so boot installer in UEFI boot mode.Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Oh geez... I just did it like you said, and it worked. So easy, but I guess I was so out I chose other boot mode. I am writing this comment from freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04. Thank you for your time and help, oldfred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have Windows in one boot mode, UEFI? and then Ubuntu in other boot mode BIOS?

Both systems must be in same boot mode, preferably UEFI.

And both install based on how you boot install media, so boot installer in UEFI boot mode.

Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8

[How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi)

Also found that for those using Rufus that this screen shows a BIOS/MBR configuration. The Ubuntu install ISO is for both UEFI and BIOS, but Rufus seems to only make one or the other. For UEFI select gpt & UEFI.

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#2